# SKip the variable that start with a word and ends BY number [0-9]

Tags: php, expression, match

I have this array `arr("PAPER","SHEET","SHEET1","SHEET2", "SHEET3")` with a loop `foreach(key,value)`. I will skip the variable that start with "SHEET" and ends with a number `[0-9]`

How to do this with `preg_math` or other REGEX?

```
if(Condition){
Code...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
if (preg_match('/^SHEET\d+$/i', $value)) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Right answer Thanks

Comment: @logitech2004 then mark it as "accepted"

Comment: If answer really helps you, its your sole responsibility to accept the answer or at least upvote an answer @logitech2004

Comment: if (preg_match('/^SHEET|/^SHEET\d+$/i', $value)) {
    continue;
} is correct?